# Count the number of rows with the same id [PHP]

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

So I want to count and echo the number of rows from `table2`, which have the same `id` `row` as `table1`.

I understand the function `mysqli_num_rows` funtion, but how can I make it count the `rows` from `table2` that have the matching `id`?

Total newbie, and still searching. Thought this might help me get in the right direction. Thanks for any help !

Comment: You should do this in the database - don't do it in PHP.

Comment: @mzedeler may I ask why that's not a good idea?

Comment: Because you'll get a lot of traffic between PHP and mysql. It'll perform much worse than just letting mysql do all the work.

Answer (score 1):

mysqli_num_rows return the number of rows from a result.
You should write an other query to return the number of rows in table 2 with the same id

```
SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM table2
WHERE table2.id = <id>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
CREATE TABLE table1 (id INT);
CREATE TABLE table2 (id INT);

INSERT INTO table1 VALUES (1), (2), (3), (4);
INSERT INTO table2 VALUES (2), (4);

SELECT COUNT(*)
  FROM table1
  JOIN table2
    ON table1.id = table2.id;
```

Try it here: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/0d289/1

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
    SELECT `table2`.`id`, COUNT(`table2`.`id`) AS `num_rows`
    FROM `table2`
    LEFT JOIN `table1` ON `table2`.`id` = `table1`.`id`
    WHERE `table2`.`id` IS NOT NULL
    GROUP BY `table2`.`id`
    ORDER BY `table2`.`id` ASC
```

Answer (score 0):

To only count

```
select count(*)
  from table1, table2
  where  table1.id = table2.id
```

To know what id  and how much

```
select table2.id, count(*)
  from table1, table2
    where  table1.id = table2.id
  group by table2.id
```

[**The second case on sqlfiddle.com**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/cd4ca/4)